# Error: Cannot find module '../config/env' when use ```npm start```command

Tags: reactjs, npm

Unfortunately, as I type `npm start` command, there in unexpected error. Options from the following discussions are not useful for the mac.

https://www.google.com/url?q=https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/6950&sa=D&source=hangouts&ust=1605624698772000&usg=AFQjCNHopXPtIHDOftJpnxm7EGuQNSSVMw

Is there any other solution please?

The error is shown in the snapshot.[image: npm start error]

Comment: did you run npm install?

Comment: Yes, I ran npm install. It also gave me couple of warnings like ```npm WARN ws@7.4.0 requires a peer of utf-8-validate@^5.0.2 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
```